No audio when sharing screen/chrome tab on Google Meet
Problem:

Audio is already working in Chrome, but once I present a Chrome tab with audio in Google Meet I can't hear any audio from that tab and neither can anyone else in the meeting. I still can see progress on the audio's seek bar but no sound. I'm able to hear audio once the sharing stops.
Screen sharing with audio works fine in other applications except Google Meet.
My sound card has no stereo mix for some reason, and I'm not sure if it's relevant. I tried presenting a Chrome tab with audio on other laptops that have stereo mix (albeit disabled) and it works fine.

Hardware:
I'm running Windows 11 on an old (2010) Lenovo G550 which works good and it's fast for normal everyday tasks. Sound card driver is up-to-date, same for Chrome [Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)]
Things I tried:

Un- and reinstalling Chrome.
Un- and reinstalling of sound card driver.
Removing all site data/cookies for Google, including Meet.
Allowing sound in site settings for both Chrome Meet tab and the 'audio' tab.
Playing online and offline audio files.
Disabling all Chrome extensions.

I would appreciate any suggestions.
